# CSS - How can I set the content to attr() but when attribute isn't available, set it to 0 or another?

Tags: css

I have some style:

```
input::before {
    content: attr(min); 
}
```

and some html:

```
<input type="range">
```

The `input` element has no max attribute and the content will be nothing.

Can I set the specific value that will be the content if the attribute isn't available, or can I get the minimum value of the slider??

( Only CSS Please )

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
input::before {
    content: attr(min, integer, 0); 
}
```

Or:

```
input::before {
    content: attr(min, number, 0); 
}
```

Replace the 0 with the number you want.

Comment: Do you have an example

Comment: Is there any actual browser support for that?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a bit of CSS trickery. First, you'd set both the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to have an initial `content: "0";`. Then position them in the same place, with a background color. This means they'll overlap. After this, set the `content` of `::after` to `attr(min)`. If there is a `min` attribute, the  `::after` element will have width and hide the `::before`.

```css
input[type="range"] {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"]:after,
input[type="range"]:before {
  content: '0';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  background: white;
}

input[type="range"]:after {
  content: attr(min);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="20" max="100" />
<input type="range" max="100" />
```

Comment: it works, but the before should used for the max attribute

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the `content` property of the pseudo-element(s) a default value of "0" and then overwrite the value(s) for inputs with the relevant attribute(s) present.

Here's a very quick example:

```css
*{color:#000;font-family:arial,sans serif;}
[type=range]::before,
[type=range]::after{
  content:"0";
}
[type=range][min]::before{
  content:attr(min);
}
[type=range][max]::after{
  content:attr(max);
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
<input max="5" min="1" type="range">
```